# Create Separate Folders Based on Files Prefix And Copy Them Accordingly

Tags: python, bash

I have a set of files ranging like this:

```
Doc0001-done.xlsx,
Doc0001-status.xlsx,
Doc0001-pending.xlsx,

Doc0002-done.xlsx,
Doc0002-status.xlsx,
Doc0002-pending.xlsx,

Doc0483-done.xlsx,
Doc0483-status.xlsx,
Doc0483-pending.xlsx,
```

How can I write a script to help me create a separate folder for each prefix and then copy the files accordingly, like create a Folder for Doc0001 and copy the done, status and pending there, and so on with the other prefixes. There are too many, it would take me an eternity. Really thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
from shutil import copyfile
path_to_files = '/Users/path_to_dir_with_files'
files = os.listdir(path_to_files)
for file in files:
    if file.startswith('Doc'):
        _dir = file[:file.find('-')]
        if _dir not in os.listdir(path_to_files):
            os.mkdir(f'{path_to_files}/{_dir}')
        copyfile(f'{path_to_files}/{file}', f'{path_to_files}/{_dir}/{file}')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can a brace expansion with a pathname expansion. To make the folders you do.

`mkdir Doc{0001..0483}`

Where Doc{0001..0483} is a brace expansion which expands to Doc0001 Doc0002 ... Doc0483.
To move the files to the folder you would do

`for x in Doc{0001..0483}; do mv $x* $x; done`

where * corresponds to pathname expansion which expands to all the files beginning with $x (note pathname expansion happens after parameter expansion which makes this possible).